# XCode 6.1: All commands in Debug menu greyed out

Tags: c++, xcode6

I am currently playing around some C++ programming with XCode. My problem is the debug menu in XCode is always greyed out. Adding breakpoints will not change this either.

I've searched a bit before asking and answers are mostly around making sure the scheme is correct. 
I checked that the LLDB debugger was selected and that an executable had been added to the target.
What else am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: I'm finding same with 6.1.1,
I've installed command line tools,
but can't figure out the problem

Comment: Is your build setting set to build in debug mode? Does your project debugs well in other version of XCode?

Comment: false alarm, at least on my behalf, this was user misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

The debugging menu items are disabled until you build and run the current scheme.

Using xcode 6.1.1 on osx 10.9.5, I selected "new > project application > command line tool" to create a simple hello world. all debug commands were greyed out

I found this confusing, as I'm used to visual studio giving me the option to begin debugging by stepping in, but when I pressed 'build and run' it stopped on the first breakpoint, and the debug menu was enabled.